# Remove Duplicate from Email and export to csv

Tags: python-3.x

I'm actually clearing my email contact database through the means of python scripting. However, I face some issue while doing so when I remove the duplicate the shape of the data frame still retain even though I check for that there is over 600 duplicates shown. You may refer to the attached codes.

I made use of .drop_duplicates function to remove the duplicate and .shape to show the size again.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

data = pd.read_csv('ToBeSort.csv')
data.shape
data['Last Name'].duplicated()
dupes = data.drop_duplicates(subset=["Last Name"], keep=False)
print(dupes.shape)
dupes.to_csv('New.csv')
```

The duplicates still surface after export to new csv. The expected output for the new csv should not have any duplicates email in it.

Comment: Thanks in advance. For the database download link can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ZrqunAgBhFdGiTlCKB8Qbux6HMvVw6j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you give an example of an duplicate that makes it through?

Comment: I actually found out a mistake I shouldn't use subset when removing duplicate since it the actual data frame will still retain its shape.

But after removing the subset and retaining the keep=False. I notice another problem is the whole data frame get shifted up to the empty space one it clear the column. May I ask what can i do to ensure the duplicates is remove without messing the original structure? Or is there another way that is easier to use email address as a reference by delimiting @ then compare the string then capture the index and remove the appropriate row?